# lroundf missing in VC++ 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Visual C++ 2012 [doesn't support](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/260e04fc-dd05-4a96-8953-9c6ea1ad62fb/cant-find-stdround-in-cmath?forum=vclanguage) [lroundf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn329049.aspx) which rounds float to long.What would be the most correct implementation of that method?

Comment: are you sure ? do you include <math.h> ? The link you provided only talk about std::round and cmath, this is different.

Comment: Tried with <math.h> and it doesn't supply lroundf or anything like that.

Comment: Strange, you can perhaps use  floor(<yourdouble> + 0.5f); then. The fact to add 0.5f will "round" your double instead of just "floor" it

Comment: Or perhaps just try with include<tgmath.h> instead of <math.h>

Comment: There is no <tgmath.h> in VC++ 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I found this implementation:

```
 inline long   lroundf(float num) { return static_cast<long>(roundf(num)); }
```

from [here](https://github.com/nu7hatch/wtf/blob/master/wtf/MathExtras.h)

where my roundf is implemented like this:

```
inline float  roundf(float num)  
{
   return num > 0 ? std::floor(num + 0.5f) : std::ceil(num - 0.5f);
}
```